# Target parent <html> and set css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="popup>
      <iframe><html>...</html></iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I want to set the parent HTML of #popup css to `css({'position':'fixed','pointer-events':'none'})` but I cant seem to target it right. When using just simply `$("html").css({'position':'fixed','pointer-events':'none'});` that does the trick, but also disables scrolling inside the iframe, so I need to target only the parent html.

Comment: Thanks to your HTML sample it's a bit unclear from where and what are you trying to target.

Comment: are you targeting the body?why not target it directly there will only be one body anyway

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i am trying to do something like $("#popup").parent("body").css(); but that doesnt work

Comment: `iframe` is usually used with a `src=""` attribute, not with HTML

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan no there are two bodies. one is window, and other is iframe..

Answer (score 3):

Try using `$("#popup").closest("body")`

I must note that it's a bit strange what you're doing with `<iframe>` Usually you'd want to use a `src=""` attribute. Why putting a `<html>` tag in it?

Comment: awesome. that does it.

Answer (score 1):

Applying css on html in not a good practice. If you want to apply css on whole document then apply on `<body>` tag.

```
$("body").css({'position':'fixed','pointer-events':'none'});
```

Try this is will work fine.

Comment: ok body then, but how do i target the parent body of the div id popup. because now it disables also the body inside the iframe..

Comment: try using `$("#popup").closest("body").css({'position':'fixed','pointer-events':'none'});`

Answer (score 0):

It should work:

```
 $( "#popup" ).closest('html').css( {'position':'fixed','pointer-events':'none'});
```

Comment: there is no element with class `popup` in the question.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri you know what `.parents()` does? it excesses the `.css` to every single ancestor of `#popup` which is a terrible overhead when you can use `.closest()` ;)